# python regex unicode - extracting data from an utf-8 file

Tags: python, regex, unicode, extract

I am facing difficulties for extracting data from an UTF-8 file that contains chinese characters.

The file is actually the CEDICT (chinese-english dictionary) and looks like this :

```
賓 宾 [bin1] /visitor/guest/object (in grammar)/
賓主 宾主 [bin1 zhu3] /host and guest/
賓利 宾利 [Bin1 li4] /Bentley/
賓士 宾士 [Bin1 shi4] /Taiwan equivalent of 奔馳|奔驰[Ben1 chi2]/
賓夕法尼亞 宾夕法尼亚 [Bin1 xi1 fa3 ni2 ya4] /Pennsylvania/
賓夕法尼亞大學 宾夕法尼亚大学 [Bin1 xi1 fa3 ni2 ya4 Da4 xue2] /University of Pennsylvania/
賓夕法尼亞州 宾夕法尼亚州 [Bin1 xi1 fa3 ni2 ya4 zhou1] /Pennsylvania/
```

Until now, I manage to get the first two fields using split() but I can't find out how I should proceed to extract the two other fields (let's say for the second line "bin1 zhu3" and "host and guest". I have been trying to use regex but it doesn't work for a reason I ignore.

```
#!/bin/python
#coding=utf-8
import re

class REMatcher(object):
    def __init__(self, matchstring):
        self.matchstring = matchstring

    def match(self,regexp):
        self.rematch = re.match(regexp, self.matchstring)
        return bool(self.rematch)

    def group(self,i):
        return self.rematch.group(i)

def look(character):
    myFile = open("/home/quentin/cedict_ts.u8","r")
    for line in myFile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        elements = line.split(" ")
        try:
            if line != "" and elements[1] == character:
                myFile.close()
                return line
        except:
            myFile.close()
            break
    myFile.close()
    return "Aucun résultat :("


translation = look("賓主") # translation contains one line of the file
elements = translation.split()
traditionnal = elements[0]
simplified = elements[1]
print "Traditionnal:" + traditionnal
print "Simplified:" + simplified

m = REMatcher(translation)
tr = ""
if m.match(r"\[(\w+)\]"):
    tr = m.group(1) 
print "Pronouciation:" + tr
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would continue to use splits instead of regular expressions, with the [maximum split number](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) given. It depends on how consistent the format of the input file is.

```
elements = translation.split(' ',2)
traditionnal = elements[0]
simplified = elements[1]
rest = elements[2]
print "Traditionnal:" + traditionnal
print "Simplified:" + simplified
elems = rest.split(']')
tr = elems[0].strip('[')
print "Pronouciation:" + tr
```

Output:

```
Traditionnal:賓主
Simplified:宾主
Pronouciation:bin1 zhu3
```

**EDIT:** To split the last field into a list, split on the `/`:

```
translations = elems[1].strip().strip('/').split('/')
#strip the spaces, then the first and last slash, 
#then split on the slashes
```

Output (for the first line of input):

```
['visitor', 'guest', 'object (in grammar)']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is indeed working for the "pronunciation" field but it becomes tricky when analyzing the last field as the character/word may have several translations. I am still curious why the regex patterns doesn't work... Always a mess when coming to unicode... :(

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do with the last field... You never said anything in the question. Also, you said "for a reason that I ignore"... well, it seems that the reason might be important! :-)

Comment: You are right : I forgot to mention it clearly. What I want to do is to extract each field of a line. As you said, I can use split() for the first three fields. For the last field, I would like to be able to extract the translations as a python list. For example, if we take the first line, transforming "/visitor/guest/object (in grammar)/" into translations = ("visitor", "guest", "object(in grammar)").

Comment: It's working like a charm. Thank you very much darthbith (sorry I can't upvote for your answer as I need 15 reputation points for doing so !?).

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark underneath the up/down vote. That will give me and you some reputation :-)

Comment: I tried doing this before using splits, the problem is that the character/pronunciation length is not consistent through the file. I managed to get it working using regex-with-grouping.

Comment: @sircodesalot, I have tried this solution on several lines : it seems to work. The pronunciations are always circled by "[]" so why the inconsistencies with the length could cause a problem ?

Comment: @darthbith : done ! (sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow ;))

Comment: It's not to say you *can't* do it, but that it takes extra processing. For example, you have to handle the characters different from how you handle the braces (you have to split for `[ ]`, which is different from how you handle the definitions (similar to `[ ]` but you have multiple items to read through. If you use a regex, you can process the entire line with just two or three lines of code.

Comment: I only mention it because I initially tried doing it using `split` and it turned into such a headache. Learning regex was initially painful, but it's too important a programming tool not to know in general.

Comment: @sircodesalot Like I said in my answer, it depends on how consistent the format of the input file is :-) Agreed about the importance of regex though. Saved my butt many times.

Answer (score 3):

This builds a dictionary to look up translations by either simplified or traditional characters and works in both Python 2.7 and 3.3:

```
# coding: utf8
import re
import codecs

# Process the whole file decoding from UTF-8 to Unicode
with codecs.open('cedict_ts.u8',encoding='utf8') as datafile:
    D = {}
    for line in datafile:
        # Skip comment lines
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        trad,simp,pinyin,trans = re.match(r'(.*?) (.*?) \[(.*?)\] /(.*)/',line).groups()
        D[trad] = (simp,pinyin,trans)
        D[simp] = (trad,pinyin,trans)
```

Output (Python 3.3):

```
>>> D['马克']
('馬克', 'Ma3 ke4', 'Mark (name)')
>>> D['一路顺风']
('一路順風', 'yi1 lu4 shun4 feng1', 'to have a pleasant journey (idiom)')
>>> D['馬克']
('马克', 'Ma3 ke4', 'Mark (name)')
```

Output (Python 2.7, you have to print strings to see non-ASCII characters):

```
>>> D[u'马克']
(u'\u99ac\u514b', u'Ma3 ke4', u'Mark (name)')
>>> print D[u'马克'][0]
馬克
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was describing in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Heh, I've done this exact same thing before. Basically you just need to use regex with groupings. Unfortunately, I don't know python regex super well (I did the same thing using C#), but you should really do something like this:

matcher = `"(\b\w+\b) (\b\w+\b) \[(\.*?)\] /(.*?)/"`

basically you match the entire line using one expression, but then you use `( )` to separate each item into a regex-group. Then you just need to read the groups and voila!

Comment: +1 This would probably work, and on only 1 line too! Does the `\w` in regex match unicode characters? I guess it probably depends on the implementation....

Comment: It shoooould, but i've never used python's implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sircodesalot. This is what I wanted to do at first but the python regex don't seem to match when I try it out . With simple ASCII text, it's working but not with unicode data...

Comment: For the moment, I think I'm going to use darthbith solution (seems to work :). If I encounter some quirks later, I will certainly have to fall back using a regex solution.

Comment: I think when I did this originally, I just used the unicode start and end range, so something like (in C#): [\u4E00-\u9FFF]. where U+4E00-U+9FFF are the hex codes for the chinese character code plane start and end ranges.

Comment: If you're going to use darthbith's answer, be sure to give him some points!

Comment: (In addition to selecting his answer [the green check] you can also up-vote his answer [the up arrow]). Since you're new, upvoting means the answer is 'helpful' (+5) where accepting means that it's the best solution (+10).